# GET elements in the url are missing after after submitting in POST format

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

> here is my code

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!=''){

$id= get_safe_value($con, $_GET['id']);
$res=mysqli_query($con, "select * from `categories` where id='$id'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$categories=$row['categories'];
}


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$categories= get_safe_value($con, $_POST['categories']);
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!=''){
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `categories` SET `categories`='$categories' WHERE `categories`.`id`=$id");
}else{
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `categories` ( `categories`,`status` ) VALUES ('$categories', '1')");
}
echo "<script>window.location.href='categories.php'</script>";
die();
}
```

> to edit my categories, i sent id to the url like this

```
echo "<a href='manage-categories.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Edit </a>";
```

but after form submission, that second if block unable to catch the id. Any solution?

> this is my form

```
     <form method="POST" action="manage-categories.php">
      <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
           <h4 class="card-title">Insert Categories</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-block">
          <div class="card-body">

            <h5 class="mt-2">Category Name</h5>
                  <fieldset class="form-group">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="placeholderInput" value="<?php echo $categories; ?>" name="categories" placeholder="Enter category name">
                  </fieldset>
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1" name="submit" type="submit" value="Insert">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field_error">
                    <?php
                    echo "<p>";
                    echo $msg;
                    echo "</p>";
                    ?></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

> This form is used for both updation and insert

Comment: You said it yourself... If the HTML form has a POST type you have to make your handling in $_POST and if it was in GET then you should use $_GET... Please, provide the HTML form or more code so that we can understand how you are submitting the POST/GET request

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.  Whatever your "get_safe_value" function is doing almost certainly isn't safe

Comment: very thank you for this valuable information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET and POST values don't persist between requests. When you submit a form, you're making a new request to a new URL.

To ensure the value is sent to the server again when submitting the form, you can either:

1. put the querystring (GET) parameter into the URL you send to when submitting the form e.g. by injecting it into the form's "action" attribute.

Or

2. create a hidden field in your form which contains the relevant ID, and then make your PHP code search for `$_POST["id"]` instead of the GET version.

Answer (score 1):

The action in the form most likley does not have the Query String defined.

```
<form method="post" action="manage-categories.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
...
```

Make sure you truely post with the query string.

Comment: No problem. Would you please set the answer as correct? @kiran